# Using php.ini to turn output_buffering on

Tags: php

Hi I am attempting to turn output_buffering on in PHP. When I locate my PHP configuration page in my browser, however, my "loaded configuration file" is (none) and my "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" is /etc.

Other Stackoverflow threads have suggested that I should copy php.ini-dist to /usr/local/lib/php.ini. When I try and do this, however, I get an error that I have to create a database.

Can someone explicitly run through how I obtain a /usr/local/lib/php.ini path so I can turn output_buffering on?

Thank you very much... I have just found previous threads on this issue confusing.

Comment: I think you should just edit your `/etc/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Place your `php.ini` to setting of `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` from output of `phpinfo()`. The path is compiled in.